# Web cam integration in .net MVC

Tags: c#, actionscript, webcam

I am a new bee to this .net MVC basically i am from PHP. I am trying to integrate web cam in my MVC app. I am using Flash to integrate it, I have written an action script to capture the image from web cam, but i am unable to upload it to DB. I tried with communicating javascript and and actionsctipt but its not working out for me. Any valuable inputs for me is appreciated

Plz help me anybody....... :(

Sameer Joshi

Comment: You need to add more details. Maybe some code of what you wrote. If your proficient in JavaScript/Actionscript, you should be able to send an HttpPostedFile to an action coded in MVC and have it do the rest there.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297954/uploading-files-with-asp-net-mvc-get-name-but-no-file-stream-what-am-i-doing-w

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to post the file from your Flash applet to a .NET page / service / http handler / MVC Action which will actually write the image to your DB.

I would suggest simply posting the file to an appropriate action on an appropriate controller. An action along the lines of (assuming this is in the "Files" Controller)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult  SaveFile(HttpPostedFile uploadedFile)
{
    // write file to DB / save to disk here
    RedirectToAction(......);
}
```

So from your Flash applet, you'd post the file to www.site.com/files/savefile

Answer (score -1):

You may also check Silverlight 4 support for microphone and webcam.

[Webcam and Microphone Showcase](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Silverlight4/MagicMirror/)

George.