# Uploading pictures

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Goal:
Upload a picture that shall be saved in the asp.net MVC project created in Visual Studio 2010.

Questions:

Should the pictures be saved in my SQL server express or VS 2010's Content/Images and why?

The requirement specifications are:

- The width and height should be max 200 pixels
- The file format should be png, gif and jpeg
- The picture's size is max 1 mb.

What sourcecode do I need?

Can somebody can recommend a good website about the sourcecode of uploading a picture?

Comment: It depends.  What will you do with the pictures?

Comment: The pictures should display in my webshop application only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should the pictures be saved in my SQL server express or VS 2010's Content/Images and why?

To answer this question, read [this](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=64525) article.

---

You can find code to upload files in [many](http://forums.asp.net/t/1237419.aspx) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297954/uploading-files-with-asp-net-mvc-get-name-but-no-file-stream-what-am-i-doing-w).

Adapting it so only files of your specifications will be saved is left as an exercise for the reader.