# ASP.NET MVC3 RAZOR: File Upload gives zero as file count

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to upload multiple files into web server using MVC3 with RAZOR. I have the following code. In the controller, I am getting zero as the file count. How to correct it to get the actual number of files being uploaded and to get the content?

```
public class MyFileController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult MyFileProcessActionTest()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyFileProcessActionTest(IEnumerable<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {

        int fileCount = files.Count<System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase>();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "MyFileProcessActionTest";
}

<h2>MyFileProcessActionTest</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />

<input type="submit"  />

}
```

READING:

1. [Binding HttpPostedFileBase using Ajax.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491230/binding-httppostedfilebase-using-ajax-beginform)
2. ASP.NET MVC Uploading and Downloading Files
   http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/125/ASP.NET-MVC-Uploading-and-Downloading-Files
3. [How do I Validate the File Type of a File Upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944/how-do-i-validate-the-file-type-of-a-file-upload)
4. [MVC 3 file upload and model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784225/mvc-3-file-upload-and-model-binding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your form to match the following

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("action","controller",FormMethod.Post,new{encType = "multipart/form-data"})){
{

<input type="file" name="files[0]" id="file1" />
<input type="file" name="files[1]" id="file2" />
<input type="file" name="files[2]" id="file3" />

<input type="submit"  />

}
```

indices 0,1,2 will allow modelbinder to bind to `IEnumerable` furthermore `encType` also has to be specified when posting files to the server

Comment: Thanks. Worked. @using (Html.BeginForm("MyFileProcessActionTest", "MyFile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

Comment: I am getting `file` as `null` and `Request.Files.Count` is 0 too, would there be any difference if the `form` is an `AjaxForm` and there are `routeValues` as well?

Comment: bjan, I have not tested it with ajax, but i believe it should work even with ajax.

Comment: @bjan You cannot upload file that way with ajax... you should search on google `How to upload a file with ajax using an iframe`

Answer (score 8):

You must include the `enctype` attribute in the `form` tag to indicate that the form should include files.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("YourAction", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"))
{
}
```

Comment: Very often people miss enctype="multipart/form-data" for forms that contains file upload

Comment: i believe we can't post files using `GET` method either

Comment: I am getting `file` as `null` and `Request.Files.Count` is 0 too, would there be any difference if the `form` is an `AjaxForm` and there are `routeValues` as well?

Comment: @bjan You cannot upload file that way with ajax... you should search on google How to upload a file with ajax using an iframe